# htaccess regex redirect url not containing lang-xx to same url with lang-es

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have never used htaccess redirections, I am using prestashop 1.3 and have duplicated urls in the way

```
http://www.domain.com/catyegory/product.html
http://www.domain.com/lang-es/catyegory/product.html

http://www.domain.com/catyegory-1/product.html
http://www.domain.com/lang-es/catyegory-1/product.html
```

This problem does not happend with other languages and I need to rediret the urls that not contain any **lang-xx** to the same url with **lang-es**

I am trying with that, but does not work

```
Redirect 301 !([ lang-es)(*.) http://www.domain.com/lang-es/$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in your expression (no closing `[`), also you should use `RewriteCond` to get the "does not start with" expression:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lang-es/.*
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/lang-es/$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Amine I am going to try that